# up/down arrow scroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

up/down arrow scroll not working in jquery scrolify plugin.I want to do the scroll with both page up/down button and in up/down arrow button click.
page up/down arrow working fine as I expect.up/down button click not scroll as page scroll

```
           if(e.keyCode==33 ) { //working

                if(index>0) {
                    if(atTop()) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        index--;
                        //index, instant, callbacks
                        animateScroll(index,false,true);
                    }
                }
            } else if(e.keyCode==34) { //working
                if(index<heights.length-1) {
                    if(atBottom()) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        index++;
                        //index, instant, callbacks
                        animateScroll(index,false,true);
                    }
                }
            }
            if(e.keyCode==38) {  //not working
                if(index>0) {
                    if(atTop()) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        index--;
                        //index, instant, callbacks
                        animateScroll(index,false,true);
                        console.log('up arrow');
                    }
                }
            } else if(e.keyCode==40) {  //not working
                if(index<heights.length-1) {
                    if(atBottom()) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        index++;
                        //index, instant, callbacks
                        animateScroll(index,false,true);
                        console.log('down arrow');
                    }
                }
            }
```

```js
/*!
 * jQuery Scrollify
 * Version 1.0.5
 *
 * Requires:
 * - jQuery 1.7 or higher
 *
 * https://github.com/lukehaas/Scrollify
 *
 * Copyright 2016, Luke Haas
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of
 * this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in
 * the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to
 * use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of
 * the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so,
 * subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
 * copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS
 * FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR
 * COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER
 * IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN
 * CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.



 If section being scrolled to is an interstitialSection and the last section on page

 then value to scroll to is current position plus height of interstitialSection

 */
 

(function (global,factory) {
 "use strict";
 if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
  // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
  define(['jquery'], function($) {
   return factory($, global, global.document);
  });
 } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
  // Node/CommonJS
  module.exports = function( root, jQuery ) {
   if ( jQuery === undefined ) {
    // require('jQuery') returns a factory that requires window to
    // build a jQuery instance, we normalize how we use modules
    // that require this pattern but the window provided is a noop
    // if it's defined (how jquery works)
    if ( typeof window !== 'undefined' ) {
     jQuery = require('jquery');
    } else {
     jQuery = require('jquery')(root);
    }
   }
   factory(jQuery, global, global.document);
   return jQuery;
  };
 } else {
  // Browser globals
  factory(jQuery, global, global.document);
 }
}(typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : this, function ($, window, document, undefined) {
 "use strict";
 var heights = [],
  names = [],
  elements = [],
  overflow = [],
  index = 0,
  currentIndex = 0,
  interstitialIndex = 1,
  hasLocation = false,
  timeoutId,
  timeoutId2,
  $window = $(window),
  top = $window.scrollTop(),
  scrollable = false,
  locked = false,
  scrolled = false,
  manualScroll,
  swipeScroll,
  util,
  disabled = false,
  scrollSamples = [],
  scrollTime = new Date().getTime(),
  firstLoad = true,
  initialised = false,
  wheelEvent = 'onwheel' in document ? 'wheel' : document.onmousewheel !== undefined ? 'mousewheel' : 'DOMMouseScroll',
  settings = {
   //section should be an identifier that is the same for each section
   section: ".section",
   //sectionName: "section-name",
   interstitialSection: "",
   easing: "easeOutExpo",
   scrollSpeed: 500,
   offset : 0,
   scrollbars: true,
   target:"html,body",
   standardScrollElements: false,
   setHeights: true,
   overflowScroll:true,
   before:function() {},
   after:function() {},
   afterResize:function() {},
   afterRender:function() {}
  };
 function animateScroll(index,instant,callbacks) {
  if(currentIndex===index) {
   callbacks = false;
  }
  if(disabled===true) {
   return true;
  }
  if(names[index]) {
   scrollable = false;
   if(callbacks) {
    settings.before(index,elements);
   }
   interstitialIndex = 1;
   if(settings.sectionName && !(firstLoad===true && index===0)) {
    if(history.pushState) {
        try {
       history.replaceState(null, null, names[index]);
        } catch (e) {
         if(window.console) {
          console.warn("Scrollify warning: This needs to be hosted on a server to manipulate the hash value.");
         }
        }

    } else {
     window.location.hash = names[index];
    }
   }
   if(instant) {
    $(settings.target).stop().scrollTop(heights[index]);
    if(callbacks) {
     settings.after(index,elements);
    }
   } else {
    locked = true;
    if( $().velocity ) {
     $(settings.target).stop().velocity('scroll', {
       duration: settings.scrollSpeed,
       easing: settings.easing,
       offset: heights[index],
       mobileHA: false
      });
    } else {
     $(settings.target).stop().animate({
      scrollTop: heights[index]
     }, settings.scrollSpeed,settings.easing);
    }

    if(window.location.hash.length && settings.sectionName && window.console) {
     try {
      if($(window.location.hash).length) {
       console.warn("Scrollify warning: There are IDs on the page that match the hash value - this will cause the page to anchor.");
      }
     } catch (e) {
      console.warn("Scrollify warning:", window.location.hash, "is not a valid jQuery expression.");
     }
    }
    $(settings.target).promise().done(function(){
     currentIndex = index;
     locked = false;
     firstLoad = false;
     if(callbacks) {
      settings.after(index,elements);
     }
    });
   }

  }
 }

 function isAccelerating(samples) {
    function average(num) {
     var sum = 0;

     var lastElements = samples.slice(Math.max(samples.length - num, 1));

          for(var i = 0; i < lastElements.length; i++){
              sum += lastElements[i];
          }

          return Math.ceil(sum/num);
    }

    var avEnd = average(10);
        var avMiddle = average(70);

        if(avEnd >= avMiddle) {
     return true;
    } else {
     return false;
    }
 }
 $.scrollify = function(options) {
  initialised = true;

  $.easing['easeOutExpo'] = function(x, t, b, c, d) {
   return (t==d) ? b+c : c * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * t/d) + 1) + b;
  };

  manualScroll = {
   /*handleMousedown:function() {
    if(disabled===true) {
     return true;
    }
    scrollable = false;
    scrolled = false;
   },*/
   handleMouseup:function() {
    if(disabled===true) {
     return true;
    }
    scrollable = true;
    if(scrolled) {
     //instant,callbacks
     manualScroll.calculateNearest(false,true);
    }
   },
   handleScroll:function() {
    if(disabled===true) {
     return true;
    }
    if(timeoutId){
     clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }

    timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
     scrolled = f;
     if(scrollable===false) {
      return false;
     }
     scrollable = false;

     //instant,callbacks
     manualScroll.calculateNearest(false,false);
    }, 200);
   },
   calculateNearest:function(instant,callbacks) {
    top = $window.scrollTop();
    var i =1,
     max = heights.length,
     closest = 0,
     prev = Math.abs(heights[0] - top),
     diff;
    for(;i<max;i++) {
     diff = Math.abs(heights[i] - top);

     if(diff < prev) {
      prev = diff;
      closest = i;
     }
    }
    if(atBottom() || atTop()) {
     index = closest;
     //index, instant, callbacks
     animateScroll(closest,instant,callbacks);
    }
   },
   /*wheel scroll*/
   wheelHandler:function(e) {

    if(disabled===true) {
     return true;
    } else if(settings.standardScrollElements) {
     if($(e.target).is(settings.standardScrollElements) || $(e.target).closest(settings.standardScrollElements).length) {
      return true;
     }
    }
    if(!overflow[index]) {
     e.preventDefault();
    }
    var currentScrollTime = new Date().getTime();



    e = e || window.event;
    var value = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -e.originalEvent.deltaY || -e.originalEvent.detail;
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, value));



    //delta = delta || -e.originalEvent.detail / 3 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120;


    if(scrollSamples.length > 149){
     scrollSamples.shift();
    }
    //scrollSamples.push(Math.abs(delta*10));
    scrollSamples.push(Math.abs(value));

    if((currentScrollTime-scrollTime) > 200){
     scrollSamples = [];
    }
    scrollTime = currentScrollTime;


    if(locked) {
     return false;
    }

    if(delta<0) {
     if(index<heights.length-1) {
      if(atBottom()) {
       if(isAccelerating(scrollSamples)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        index++;
        locked = true;
        //index, instant, callbacks
        animateScroll(index,false,true);
       } else {
        return false;
       }
      }
     }
    } else if(delta>0) {
     if(index>0) {
      if(atTop()) {
       if(isAccelerating(scrollSamples)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        index--;
        locked = true;
        //index, instant, callbacks
        animateScroll(index,false,true);
       } else {
        return false
       }
      }
     }
    }

   },
   /*end of wheel*/
   keyHandler:function(e) {
    if(disabled===true) {
     return true;
    }
    if(locked===true) {
     return false;
    }
    if(e.keyCode==33 ) {
     
     if(index>0) {
      if(atTop()) {
       e.preventDefault();
       index--;
       //index, instant, callbacks
       animateScroll(index,false,true);
      }
     }
    } else if(e.keyCode==34) {
     if(index<heights.length-1) {
      if(atBottom()) {
       e.preventDefault();
       index++;
       //index, instant, callbacks
       animateScroll(index,false,true);
      }
     }
    }
    if(e.keyCode==38) {
     if(index>0) {
      if(atTop()) {
       e.preventDefault();
       index--;
       //index, instant, callbacks
       animateScroll(index,false,true);
       console.log('up arrow');
      }
     }
    } else if(e.keyCode==40) {
     if(index<heights.length-1) {
      if(atBottom()) {
       e.preventDefault();
       index++;
       //index, instant, callbacks
       animateScroll(index,false,true);
       console.log('down arrow');
      }
     }
    }
    /*home, end button testing*/
    if(e.keyCode==35) {
     
      for(index=6;index<1;index--)
      {
       console.log("worked on end button");
      }
     
    } 
    else if(e.keyCode==36) {
     
      for(index=0;intex<1;index++)
      {
       console.log("worked on home button");
      }
     
    } 
    /*home,end button end*/
   },
   init:function() {
    if(settings.scrollbars) {
     $window.on('mousedown', manualScroll.handleMousedown);
     $window.on('mouseup', manualScroll.handleMouseup);
     $window.on('scroll', manualScroll.handleScroll);
    } else {
     $("body").css({"overflow":"hidden"});
    }
    $window.on(wheelEvent,manualScroll.wheelHandler);
    $(document).bind(wheelEvent,manualScroll.wheelHandler);
    $window.on('keydown', manualScroll.keyHandler);
   }
  };

  swipeScroll = {
   touches : {
    "touchstart": {"y":-1,"x":-1},
    "touchmove" : {"y":-1,"x":-1},
    "touchend"  : false,
    "direction" : "undetermined"
   },
   options:{
    "distance" : 30,
    "timeGap" : 800,
    "timeStamp" : new Date().getTime()
   },
   touchHandler: function(event) {
    if(disabled===true) {
     return true;
    } else if(settings.standardScrollElements) {
     if($(event.target).is(settings.standardScrollElements) || $(event.target).closest(settings.standardScrollElements).length) {
      return true;
     }
    }
    var touch;
    if (typeof event !== 'undefined'){
     if (typeof event.touches !== 'undefined') {
      touch = event.touches[0];
      switch (event.type) {
       case 'touchstart':
        swipeScroll.touches.touchstart.y = touch.pageY;
        swipeScroll.touches.touchmove.y = -1;

        swipeScroll.touches.touchstart.x = touch.pageX;
        swipeScroll.touches.touchmove.x = -1;

        swipeScroll.options.timeStamp = new Date().getTime();
        swipeScroll.touches.touchend = false;
       case 'touchmove':
        swipeScroll.touches.touchmove.y = touch.pageY;
        swipeScroll.touches.touchmove.x = touch.pageX;
        if(swipeScroll.touches.touchstart.y!==swipeScroll.touches.touchmove.y && (Math.abs(swipeScroll.touches.touchstart.y-swipeScroll.touches.touchmove.y)>Math.abs(swipeScroll.touches.touchstart.x-swipeScroll.touches.touchmove.x))) {
         //if(!overflow[index]) {
          event.preventDefault();
         //}
         swipeScroll.touches.direction = "y";
         if((swipeScroll.options.timeStamp+swipeScroll.options.timeGap)<(new Date().getTime()) && swipeScroll.touches.touchend == false) {

          swipeScroll.touches.touchend = true;
          if (swipeScroll.touches.touchstart.y > -1) {

           if(Math.abs(swipeScroll.touches.touchmove.y-swipeScroll.touches.touchstart.y)>swipeScroll.options.distance) {
            if(swipeScroll.touches.touchstart.y < swipeScroll.touches.touchmove.y) {

             swipeScroll.up();

            } else {
             swipeScroll.down();

            }
           }
          }
         }
        }
        break;
       case 'touchend':
        if(swipeScroll.touches[event.type]===false) {
         swipeScroll.touches[event.type] = true;
         if (swipeScroll.touches.touchstart.y > -1 && swipeScroll.touches.touchmove.y > -1 && swipeScroll.touches.direction==="y") {

          if(Math.abs(swipeScroll.touches.touchmove.y-swipeScroll.touches.touchstart.y)>swipeScroll.options.distance) {
           if(swipeScroll.touches.touchstart.y < swipeScroll.touches.touchmove.y) {
            swipeScroll.up();

           } else {
            swipeScroll.down();

           }
          }
          swipeScroll.touches.touchstart.y = -1;
          swipeScroll.touches.touchstart.x = -1;
          swipeScroll.touches.direction = "undetermined";
         }
        }
       default:
        break;
      }
     }
    }
   },
   down: function() {
    if(index<=heights.length-1) {

     if(atBottom() && index<heights.length-1) {

      index++;
      //index, instant, callbacks
      animateScroll(index,false,true);
     } else {
      if(Math.floor(elements[index].height()/$window.height())>interstitialIndex) {

       interstitialScroll(parseInt(heights[index])+($window.height()*interstitialIndex));
       interstitialIndex += 1;

      } else {
       interstitialScroll(parseInt(heights[index])+(elements[index].height()-$window.height()));
      }

     }
    }
   },
   up: function() {
    if(index>=0) {
     if(atTop() && index>0) {

      index--;
      //index, instant, callbacks
      animateScroll(index,false,true);
     } else {

      if(interstitialIndex>2) {

       interstitialIndex -= 1;
       interstitialScroll(parseInt(heights[index])+($window.height()*interstitialIndex));

      } else {

       interstitialIndex = 1;
       interstitialScroll(parseInt(heights[index]));
      }
     }

    }
   },
   init: function() {
    if (document.addEventListener) {
     document.addEventListener('touchstart', swipeScroll.touchHandler, false);
     document.addEventListener('touchmove', swipeScroll.touchHandler, false);
     document.addEventListener('touchend', swipeScroll.touchHandler, false);
    }
   }
  };


  util = {
   refresh:function(withCallback) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId2);
    timeoutId2 = setTimeout(function() {
     sizePanels();
     calculatePositions(true);
     if(withCallback) {
       settings.afterResize();
     }
    },400);
   },
   handleUpdate:function() {
    util.refresh(false);
   },
   handleResize:function() {
    util.refresh(true);
   }
  };
  settings = $.extend(settings, options);

  sizePanels();

  calculatePositions(false);

  if(true===hasLocation) {
   //index, instant, callbacks
   animateScroll(index,false,true);
  } else {
   setTimeout(function() {
    //instant,callbacks
    manualScroll.calculateNearest(true,false);
   },200);
  }
  if(heights.length) {
   manualScroll.init();
   swipeScroll.init();

   $window.on("resize",util.handleResize);
   if (document.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", util.handleResize, false);
   }
  }
  function interstitialScroll(pos) {
   if( $().velocity ) {
    $(settings.target).stop().velocity('scroll', {
     duration: settings.scrollSpeed,
     easing: settings.easing,
     offset: pos,
     mobileHA: false
    });
   } else {
    $(settings.target).stop().animate({
     scrollTop: pos
    }, settings.scrollSpeed,settings.easing);
   }
  }

  function sizePanels() {
   var selector = settings.section;
   overflow = [];
   if(settings.interstitialSection.length) {
    selector += "," + settings.interstitialSection;
   }
   $(selector).each(function(i) {
    var $this = $(this);

    if(settings.setHeights) {
     if($this.is(settings.interstitialSection)) {
      overflow[i] = false;
     } else {

      if(($this.css("height","auto").outerHeight()<$window.height()) || $this.css("overflow")==="hidden") {
       $this.css({"height":$window.height()});

       overflow[i] = false;
      } else {

       $this.css({"height":$this.height()});

       if(settings.overflowScroll) {
         overflow[i] = true;
       } else {
        overflow[i] = false;
       }
      }

     }

    } else {

     if(($this.outerHeight()<$window.height()) || (settings.overflowScroll===false)) {
      overflow[i] = false;
     } else {
      overflow[i] = true;
     }
    }
   });
  }
  function calculatePositions(resize) {
   var selector = settings.section;
   if(settings.interstitialSection.length) {
    selector += "," + settings.interstitialSection;
   }
   heights = [];
   names = [];
   elements = [];
   $(selector).each(function(i){
     var $this = $(this);
     if(i>0) {
      heights[i] = parseInt($this.offset().top) + settings.offset;
     } else {
      heights[i] = parseInt($this.offset().top);
     }
     if(settings.sectionName && $this.data(settings.sectionName)) {
      names[i] = "#" + $this.data(settings.sectionName).replace(/ /g,"-");
     } else {
      if($this.is(settings.interstitialSection)===false) {
       names[i] = "#" + (i + 1);
      } else {
       names[i] = "#";
       if(i===$(selector).length-1 && i>1) {
        heights[i] = heights[i-1]+parseInt($this.height());
       }
      }
     }
     elements[i] = $this;
     try {
      if($(names[i]).length && window.console) {
       console.warn("Scrollify warning: Section names can't match IDs on the page - this will cause the browser to anchor.");
      }
     } catch (e) {}

     if(window.location.hash===names[i]) {
      index = i;
      hasLocation = true; 
                             
     }

   });

   if(true===resize) {
    //index, instant, callbacks
    animateScroll(index,false,false);
   } else {
    settings.afterRender();
   }
  }

  function atTop() {
   if(!overflow[index]) {
    return true;
   }
   top = $window.scrollTop();
   if(top>parseInt(heights[index])) {
    return false;
   } else {
    return true;
   }
  }
  function atBottom() {
   if(!overflow[index]) {
    return true;
   }
   top = $window.scrollTop();

   if(top<parseInt(heights[index])+(elements[index].outerHeight()-$window.height())-28) {

    return false;

   } else {
    return true;
   }
  }
 }

 function move(panel,instant) {
  var z = names.length;
  for(;z>=0;z--) {
   if(typeof panel === 'string') {
    if (names[z]===panel) {
     index = z;
     //index, instant, callbacks
     animateScroll(z,instant,true);
    }
   } else {
    if(z===panel) {
     index = z;
     //index, instant, callbacks
     animateScroll(z,instant,true);
    }
   }
  }
 }
 $.scrollify.move = function(panel) {
  if(panel===undefined) {
   return false;
  }
  if(panel.originalEvent) {
   panel = $(this).attr("href");
  }
  move(panel,false);
 };
 $.scrollify.instantMove = function(panel) {
  if(panel===undefined) {
   return false;
  }
  move(panel,true);
 };
 $.scrollify.next = function() {
  if(index<names.length) {
   index += 1;
   animateScroll(index,false,true);
  }
 };
 $.scrollify.previous = function() {
  if(index>0) {
   index -= 1;
   //index, instant, callbacks
   animateScroll(index,false,true);
  }
 };
 $.scrollify.instantNext = function() {
  if(index<names.length) {
   index += 1;
   //index, instant, callbacks
   animateScroll(index,true,true);
  }
 };
 $.scrollify.instantPrevious = function() {
  if(index>0) {
   index -= 1;
   //index, instant, callbacks
   animateScroll(index,true,true);
  }
 };
 $.scrollify.destroy = function() {
  if(!initialised) {
   return false;
  }
  if(settings.setHeights) {
   $(settings.section).each(function() {
    $(this).css("height","auto");
   });
  }
  $window.off("resize",util.handleResize);
  if(settings.scrollbars) {
   $window.off('mousedown', manualScroll.handleMousedown);
   $window.off('mouseup', manualScroll.handleMouseup);
   $window.off('scroll', manualScroll.handleScroll);
  }
  $window.off(wheelEvent,manualScroll.wheelHandler);
  $window.off('keydown', manualScroll.keyHandler);

  if (document.addEventListener) {
   document.removeEventListener('touchstart', swipeScroll.touchHandler, false);
   document.removeEventListener('touchmove', swipeScroll.touchHandler, false);
   document.removeEventListener('touchend', swipeScroll.touchHandler, false);
  }
  heights = [];
  names = [];
  elements = [];
  overflow = [];
 };
 $.scrollify.update = function() {
  if(!initialised) {
   return false;
  }
  util.handleUpdate();
 };
 $.scrollify.current = function() {
  return elements[index];
 };
 $.scrollify.disable = function() {
  disabled = true;
 };
 $.scrollify.enable = function() {
  disabled = false;
  if (initialised) {
   //instant,callbacks
   manualScroll.calculateNearest(false,false);
  }
 };
 $.scrollify.isDisabled = function() {
  return disabled;
 };
 $.scrollify.setOptions = function(updatedOptions) {
  if(!initialised) {
   return false;
  }
  if(typeof updatedOptions === "object") {
   settings = $.extend(settings, updatedOptions);
   util.handleUpdate();
  } else if(window.console) {
   console.warn("Scrollify warning: Options need to be in an object.");
  }
  
 };
 
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are listening wrong event. Use `keydown event` this will work.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kMzR9/105/)

Comment: /i have added it in head portion I gave piece of code here